# Rest API for both create and update

Tags: rest, http

What is the preferred way of handling create and update request in a REST api?

On my frontend i am using the same form for both creating and updating, the only difference is that in case of update a hidden form field with id is filled.

Is it ok to send both requests to /api/post with POST method and based on the id decide whether to post or update? Or should this be handled otherwise?

Comment: Normally `POST` is for adding a new entity, then `PUT` for changes, and `DELETE` - well for removing. `GET` for queries.. etc. There's also `PATCH` for update, but IMHO `PUT` is clearer for updates..

Comment: So should i use separate URLs and methods for create and update?

Comment: Depends on what your back end supports. Btw - `api/post` is not very descriptive, it should have a name that makes sense and from that you can decide to route post/put/delete separately.

Comment: If you send a request in one way the best solution is to to use PUT with a characteristic of save using the id to indicates that is a creation or a update.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to follow REST principles, separating the endpoint like below is preferred.

```
POST  api/collections       (e.g. api/users)
PUT   api/collections/:id   (e.g. api/users/23)
```

There are 2 reasons to separate the endpoint.

- PUT has to be idempotent, while POST does not.
- If the URL of the    resource (like api/users/23) is already there,
  use PUT. If not, send POST and let the server generate
  URL. (In many cases, it uses DB’s auto-increment key)

Of course, it is up to you to decide whether you follow REST principles.

Reference
https://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/